# Best way to convert PHP block to improve site

Tags: blocks

I've just taken control over a Drupal site which the old admin used php blocks. I normally work on Joomla sites but from research and advice from others PHP blocks don't help the site in the long run.

What's the best way forward when some of the PHP blocks are set to some pages in a set area.

For example PHP block 1 is only on the Home Page's Sidebar where PHP block 2 is on Page About Us and Contact Us' Sidebar.

Just some background, This is the first Drupal site I've worked on and know only bits and pieces about Drupal apart from the general how it works and some extra details. If I've missed some research or reading which could aid in this issue which you can direct me too, this again would be great help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. The answer to this clearly depends on the PHP code on each block, without that the question is too broad I'm afraid.

Comment: @Clive I'm not so sure if they are duplicates... You know I'm not shy to vote, I do it a lot, but for this one, I wouldn't.

Comment: If the OP isnt looking for ways to create blocks programmatically I don't know what's being asked - your answer actually supports that, it's basically telling the op how to create blocks programmatically. If I'm missing something do let me know

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to move PHP code I have in PHP blocks into a more safe for the site way while still being able to be placed how they're.

Comment: @Clive From the question it looks like OP does not even know **if** he wants to create blocks in a custom module.

Comment: What's the alternative @Mołot?

Comment: @leemurphy Welcome :) Currently we don't have enough information to go on to do anything but point you to the canonical resource for creating a block programatically - if your question is different from that, or if you're struggling with a _specific_ aspect of converting block content from the PHP filter over to the custom module method, please edit the question to provide those details, and ping me (@Clive) to get it re-opened. Thanks

Comment: @Clive there is no alternative worth mentioning, I agree. I just thing his question is, how to say it, one level more abstract? One step farther from solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just make them a custom module!

The best start I can think of would be taking [block_example.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example!block_example.module/7) from the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) project as a start. Rename it, of course, and then just define your blocks in it, the way example blocks are defined. For blocks' content - move code from where it is now to appropriate functions.

That's pretty much all, if you will have more specific question during development, ask it, too.

[Understanding the hook system for Drupal modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/292) might be a useful read, too.